# dedupe merges failed with insufficient access on cross reference entity

Tags: security

Message states: 'you may not have merge access to the master record you have chosen or you encountered other errors' and then states 'insufficient access rights on cross reference id.  I checked the user access and she has CRED access on contacts (which is what she is trying to dedupe).  In her role, she is on the same level as all the contact creators.  She is able to dedupe records she created, but none that were created by her peers.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue actually ended up being relatively simple.  The object security on the contact did not have the 'Modify All' checked.  Once checked the user was able to successfully dedupe a contact.  Thank you for all of your help - you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the organisation sharing settings, she may not be allowed to edit particular contact records despite have CRUD access on Contacts.

Look at Security Settings | Sharing Settings and you will see that contacts access is controlled by access to the parent. What are your sharing settings for Accounts?

If the Accounts are, say, Public Read Only then this means she can only update Contacts associated with accounts that have been shared with her. This would be accounts she owns, accounts manually shared with her, accounts owned by those beneath her in the role hierarchy, accounts she's in the team for, by sharing rules etc.

Comment: Contact security is 'Controlled by Parent'.  Account, Contract and Asset is 'Public Read/Write'.  Since the dedupe process deletes contacts, could the account access be what is too restrictive?  Then the question would be - what should it be?

Comment: We are still having an issue with security.  Please review the last comment entered and let me know if you have any other suggestions.  Thank you.

Comment: It could be security on the child objects of Contact. When you merge the contact, the children need to be updated to reflect the new parent. So you could check, for example Cases and ensure that she has permission to edit those and all the other child object types.